# Group Messages By Latest Response

Tags: mysql

I have a table called Comments that stores messages between two users, and the table structure looks like this:

```
id | from_id | to_id | comment | date
```

I want to query the data to only display the latest message between the two parties. 
I've seen it done before.

I am using MYSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say the two users id numbers are `1` and `2`.

```
SELECT comment
FROM COMMENTS
WHERE (from_id = 1 OR from_id = 2)
AND (to_id = 1 OR to_id = 2)
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If you really wanted to be pedantic, you could add this to the where clause:

```
AND NOT (from_id = to_id)
```

to prevent cases where they send a message to themselves showing up. This assumes it's even possible for a user to send a message to them self in your system.

Comment: Change `TOP 1` to `LIMIT 1` for MySQL.

Comment: @ypercube Good spotting. I forgot the semicolon too. Damn MS SQL Server rotting my brain.

Comment: what if I wanted to query all comments that associate to only to 1 id not necessarily two. and group by the latest message of each ?

Comment: @numerical25 I'm not certain this can be done with a single SQL query. My mind has been racing for a few minutes trying to come up with some clever way to join the table on itself, but I've come up empty. Can you break this into multiple queries?

Comment: @numerical25 I accomplished this outside of the query: as I iterated through the results of the query, I kept an array of the `member_id`'s of the users I'd already displayed. Then on each iteration, I checked to see if I'd already displayed them, and if I had, I just `continue`'d the loop.  The result was a list of every conversation thread, displaying just the latest post of each.

Answer (score 3):

For User 1:

```
SELECT comment
FROM COMMENTS
WHERE (from_id = 2 AND to_id = 1) 
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0,1;
```

For User 2:

```
SELECT comment
FROM COMMENTS
WHERE (from_id = 1 AND to_id = 2) 
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0,1;
```

The "where" clause needs to ensure the message is sent from one of the two parties to the other party and vice versa, and only display the message to that user.

if it needs to display the latest message from any of the two, to both users then:

```
SELECT comment
FROM COMMENTS
WHERE (from_id = 1 OR from_id = 2)
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0,1;
```

Comment: is it possible to select all the latest message associated by only one user and group it by the last message received or sent. Example would be Google Email.

Comment: yes, just remove the "LIMIT 0,1" bit, and filter it by whatever user filter you need to apply.